# How to manage the source data for iptables -v option?

Tags: iptables

If I run the command `iptables -nvL` on my VPS server running Ubuntu I get output like (output is much longer - I have only shown the interesting parts)

$ sudo iptables -nvL

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 41439 packets, 2499K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       91.234.36.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       223.255.252.0/23     0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       1.0.1.0/24           0.0.0.0/0           
 3102  261K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 174K   54M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  495 26116 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
  331 14756 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:1723
   26  1468 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0 level 7 prefix "iptables denied: "
```

Sometimes when I run this command I get results like

```
(policy DROP 41439 packets, 2499K bytes)
```

but then other times - from within the same shell - the data gets reset back to zero and it seems to start counting again. e.g.

```
(policy DROP 2 packets, 9K bytes)
```

If I switch to a different shell I will get the same data from the last shell.
My question is

- Where is iptables is getting this info from?

  - log files?
  - does it start tracking internally from the first invocation of `iptables -nvL`?
- How can I ensure the data doesn't reset back to zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iptables keep a count (per chain) of packets processed. This two options could be used to change the count:

> -Z, --zero [chain [rulenum]]
>                 Zero the packet and byte counters in all chains, or only the given chain, or only the given rule in a chain.
>
> -c, --set-counters packets bytes
>                 This enables the administrator to initialize the packet and byte counters of a rule (during INSERT, APPEND, REPLACE operations).

Understand that some other process that calls iptables to execute INSERT, APPEND, or REPLACE operations will also change the count of packets.

Comment: thanks! this explained why the counter was reseting - it was because I was making changes to the iptables rules